# 502 Bad Gateway - NGINX only Homepage shows this error

Tags: nginx

i'm using rackspace server and just rebooted the server due to some reasons and after reboot i started the nginx service but now it shows 502 bad gateway

I already checked some error logs but still i'm unable to fix this issue

Comment: You might want to post the text from the error log here.

Comment: http://gyazo.com/42b05cce526d7b3126b28951a3e7e27c

Please have a look at this log... 
even when i try to start php service, it seems that unrecognized service... for both php and php5 and even fast cgi etc..